# CSS: styled a checkbox to look like a button, is there a hover?

Tags: css, hover, css-selectors

I've created a small looking button to display instead of a checkbox. I was wondering if there was a way to also have a :hover look somehow?

HTML:

```html
<div id="ck-button">
   <label>
      <input type="checkbox" value="1"><span>red</span>
   </label>
</div>
```

CSS:

```css
div label input {
   margin-right:100px;
}
body {
    font-family:sans-serif;
}

#ck-button {
    margin:4px;
    background-color:#EFEFEF;
    border-radius:4px;
    border:1px solid #D0D0D0;
    overflow:auto;
    float:left;
}

#ck-button label {
    float:left;
    width:4.0em;
}

#ck-button label span {
    text-align:center;
    padding:3px 0px;
    display:block;
}

#ck-button label input {
    position:absolute;
    top:-20px;
}

#ck-button input:checked + span {
    background-color:#911;
    color:#fff;
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zAFND/2/

Comment: #ck-button:hover { background: blue } for example

Answer (score 50, accepted):

```
#ck-button:hover {
    background:red;
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zAFND/4/

Answer (score 28):

it looks like you need a rule very similar to your checked rule

http://jsfiddle.net/VWBN4/3

```
#ck-button input:hover + span {
    background-color:#191;
    color:#fff;
}
```

and for hover and clicked state:

```
#ck-button input:checked:hover + span {
    background-color:#c11;
    color:#fff;
}
```

the order is important though.

Answer (score 15):

Do what Kelly said...

BUT. Instead of having the `input` positioned absolute and top `-20px` (just hiding it off the page), make the input box hidden.

example:

```
<input type="checkbox" hidden>
```

Works better and can put it anywhere on the page.

Comment: Ah...think about future users ;) not the pass..;)

Comment: Thanks for this, used Kellys code with Checkbox hidden.

Comment: I think that breaks on IE

Answer (score 4):

Do this for a cool `border` and `font` effect:

```
#ck-button:hover {             /*ADD :hover */
    margin:4px;
    background-color:#EFEFEF;
    border-radius:4px;
    border:1px solid red;      /*change border color*/ 
    overflow:auto;
    float:left;
    color:red;                 /*add font color*/
}
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/zAFND/6/

Comment: hm... that's neat but the poster didn't ask about it specifically.  Also, css comments are always `/*...*/`.

Comment: Thanks @Joseph.  Yes. I know the OP didn't ask for it... I was answering the `:hover` Q and giving my take with a little extra value.  As for the comments, yes I realize that css comments are different.  It's only for the example.  But changed anyway for realism ;-)

Comment: I see.  And actually come to think of it, using the border is a good way to not have to make a checked hover state :P

Comment: @Joseph: The last time I ratted on someone's use of `//` comments in CSS code, I got back "`//` is also valid comment syntax in Sass/SCSS" :P Personally I just call it laziness to do things the standard way (not you, Jason!). Plus, SO's syntax highlighter highlights CSS as CSS, not SCSS, and last I checked `//` is not a valid comment delimiter.

Comment: I agree @BoltClock.  I was being lazy there!  That's why I agreed w/ Joseph and made the change.

Comment: @BoltClock for me it's just OCD XD