# Make checkbox look like button

Tags: asp.net, css

In my web app (c#/MVC3), I have a huge set of checkboxes in a table. Rather than a table of checkboxes, I'd like for it to look like a wall of toggle buttons. To the user I want it to look like a wall of buttons and when they click one it is 'checked' and the button changes color.

I wasn't sure if there was CSS that could make a checkbox do this (look like a button and change colors on check rather than show a check mark), or if I would have to use some combination of buttons and javascript/jquery and hidden checkboxes or what.

Comment: Check this out - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7642277/css-styled-a-checkbox-to-look-like-a-button-is-there-a-hover

Comment: Not really an answer to your question, but I *highly recommend against this*.  In fact, I did extensive usability testing on the subject and pretty much 0% of people noticed check boxes unless they looked like native HTML check boxes.  I even wrote a [blog post](http://blog.kitchenpc.com/2012/04/13/the-white-whale-of-usability/) on the subject.

Comment: Thanks user1394965! That was exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: @JoshBlade That's ok. Mind if I put it as an answer so you can accept it? :)

Comment: @user1394965, That's fine with me.

Comment: Check this code: http://jsfiddle.net/zAFND/484/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is definitely possible to do what you want with pure CSS.

I think you should check out the jsFiddle mentioned on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7642277/css-styled-a-checkbox-to-look-like-a-button-is-there-a-hover) question.

Answer (score 2):

The jQuery UI Button widget can handle that:

http://jqueryui.com/button/#checkbox

Comment: I think the javascript from user1394965's comment to my original question is what I'm looking for. I was looking at the demo's for the jquery ui button and it looks pretty cool. At least in the demo's though, it looked like in order to select multiple buttons you have ctrl click or shift click, which I wouldn't want.

Answer (score 0):

Radio buttons are generated by the operating system and cannot be easily styled.

If you wany something different you need to generate it using CSS/images and JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I'd actually avoid doing this for usability concerns but if you still want to then read on.

This is actually quite tricky to achieve but it is possible. My solution avoids the need to assign individual IDs to your check-boxes.

Essentially, you will need an image sprite for the "on" and "off" states which you will position with the CSS background-position property, using a toggle class. Then, the following jQuery will allow you to not only swap the image state, but also confirm the respective checkbox as checked or unchecked for use of the form. Do note, that the "actual" checkbox is hidden from view but the functionality remains.

```
<form>
    <input type="checkbox" class="custom" />
</form>

<style type="text/css">
.checkbox {
    clear:left;
    float:left;
    background:url('your_image');
    background-position:top;
    width:20px;
    height:20px;
    display:block;
}
.toggled {
    background-position:bottom !important;
}
</style>

$(document).ready(function () {
    var checkboxes = $('form .custom'),
        custom = $('<span></span>').addClass('checkbox');
    checkboxes.before(custom);
    checkboxes.css('visibility', 'hidden');
    $('.checkbox').click(function () {
        $(this).toggleClass('toggled');
        var isChecked = $(this).next(':checkbox');
        var value = isChecked.prop('checked') ? 'true' : 'false';
        if (value == 'false') {
            isChecked.prop('checked', true);
        } else {
            isChecked.prop('checked', false);
        }
    });
});
```

You will, of course, have to edit the CSS to suit your exact needs. I hope this helps as this task was deceptively non-trivial.