# HTML checkboxes reset view position to the beginning of the page

Tags: php, html, css

I've used code from [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7642277/css-styled-a-checkbox-to-look-like-a-button-is-there-a-hover) which is also visible [here](http://jsfiddle.net/zAFND/2/).
I've generated number of checkboxes in PHP for a few options but when I check an option(s) and and submit a form, my PHP doesn't recognize the checkboxes' names.
Through some analysis, my conclusion is that it is because those button-like checkboxes aren't really checkboxes.
Is this true and, if so, is there any way to get PHP to recognize these checkboxes?

```
$_POST['checkBoxName']
```

generates "*Undefined index: checkBoxNam*e"

Comment: Can you show the relevant HTML code too please? I suspect I know what the issue is but I can't be 100% without it.

Comment: Generated checkbox
    `<div id="ck-button">
      <label>
          <input type="checkbox" hidden="" value="bathroom" name="place[]"></input>
      <span>Bathroom</span></label>

</div>`

(Sorry, I don't know how to display code properly in comment)

Answer (score 0):

The index of the `$_POST` variable is the name of the submitted input in the form. Based on the HTML code provided,

```
<input type="checkbox" hidden="" value="bathroom" name="place[]">
```

`$_POST['checkBoxName']` will not do anything since the name of the input is an array called `place`. Instead you want to either change the name from `place` to `checkBoxName` or do `$_POST['place']`.

Comment: I've used 'checkBoxName' in the question as an example.