# Hide table columns with CSS using adjacent selector from checkbox

Tags: html, css

I would like to hide columns in a table based on check-boxes.

Here column 2 should be hidden, as check-box *"col 2"* is not checked.

```
[v] col 1   [ ] col 2   [v] col3

+-------------------------------+
|       | col 1 | col 2 | col 3 |
| row 1 |  aaa  | bbb   | ccc   |
| row 2 |  ddd  | eee   | fff   |
+-------------------------------+
```

Currently I have a `div` container with the check-boxes, then adjacent to this div, the table.

To make things more complicated the check-boxes are "button-check-boxes", similar to this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7642302

```
<div class="filter_group">
    <div class="check_button">
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox" data-filter-col="d1"><span>col 1</span>
        </label>
    </div>
    <div class="check_button">
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox" data-filter-col="d2"><span>col 2</span>
        </label>
    </div>
    <div class="check_button">
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox" data-filter-col="d3"><span>col 3</span>
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td> </td>
        <th data-col="d1">col 1</th>
        <th data-col="d2">col 2</th>
        <th data-col="d3">col 3</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>row 1</th>
        <td data-col="d1">aaa</td>
        <td data-col="d2">bbb</td>
        <td data-col="d3">ccc</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

*(Only one data row in example code here, real table has multiple.)*

---

From what I have found, on this site and elsewhere, and if I understand the various selectors correctly, it is a slim hope - but is it possible to use *descendant* or *child combinator* in combination with *general* or *adjacent combinator*? Something in the direction of:

```
 .filter_group .check_button label input[data-filter-col="d1"]:checked ~
 table td[data-col="d1"] {
     display: none;
 }
```

If not, is there a way to do this with CSS without complicating the structure too much?

I can and am doing this with JavaScript, but was trying to solve it with CSS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since CSS selectors (including CSS level 3 and 4) only go down in the tree (including descendants, children, and younger siblings), to get this solution to work, you need the checkbox triggers to live at the same level or higher level of the DOM than the `table`.

If you do this, you could style the labels to appear like buttons, and have them in an activated state when their associated checkbox is active. Then, you can add `display: none;` to the checkbox.

However, to answer your specific question, leaving the checkboxes intact, you can attach the label to the top-level checkbox, and add two checkboxes (one active, one inactive) within the label. You can attach the label with an `id` on the top checkbox and use a `for` attribute with the same value on the `label`.

```
<input class="trigger" id="col1" type="checkbox">
<input class="trigger" id="col2" type="checkbox">
<input class="trigger" id="col3" type="checkbox">

<div class="filter_group">
    <div class="check_button">
        <label for="col1">
            <input type="checkbox" data-filter-col="d1"><input type="checkbox" data-filter-col="d1" checked><span>col 1</span>
        </label>
    </div>
    <div class="check_button">
        <label for="col2">
            <input type="checkbox" data-filter-col="d2"><input type="checkbox" data-filter-col="d2" checked><span>col 2</span>
        </label>
    </div>
    <div class="check_button">
        <label for="col3">
            <input type="checkbox" data-filter-col="d3"><input type="checkbox" data-filter-col="d3" checked><span>col 3</span>
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td> </td>
        <th data-col="d1">col 1</th>
        <th data-col="d2">col 2</th>
        <th data-col="d3">col 3</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>row 1</th>
        <td data-col="d1">aaa</td>
        <td data-col="d2">bbb</td>
        <td data-col="d3">ccc</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Then, here's the CSS to enable everything:

```
.trigger {
  /* display: none; // You would probably use this. */
  opacity: .2; /* This is to show how the wiring works. */
}

/* Default the inputs to not displaying */
.filter_group input {
  display: none;
}

/* Show and hide inline checkboxes */
#col1:not(:checked) ~ .filter_group label[for=col1] input:not(:checked),
#col2:not(:checked) ~ .filter_group label[for=col2] input:not(:checked),
#col3:not(:checked) ~ .filter_group label[for=col3] input:not(:checked){
 display: inline-block; 
}

#col1:checked ~ .filter_group label[for=col1] input:checked,
#col2:checked ~ .filter_group label[for=col2] input:checked,
#col3:checked ~ .filter_group label[for=col3] input:checked{
 display: inline-block; 
}

/* Do filters */
#col1:not(:checked) ~ * *[data-col="d1"],
#col2:not(:checked) ~ * *[data-col="d2"],
#col3:not(:checked) ~ * *[data-col="d3"] {
  display: none;
}

/* Avoid clicks on the inactive checkboxes */
label input {
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

Here's the code in action: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/xWveoz

You mention "Is there a way to do this with CSS without complicating the structure too much?"

I think this is a bit overkill. I think a cleaner strategy would be to style the `label` element directly, which removes the two non-semantic checkboxes. But, if the complexity works for you, this solution should be ample with only CSS.

Comment: Thanks mate. I moved the check-boxes up to same level as the table, use `for` on the labels and drop the other check-boxes. This works nice. Not sure I'll use it now. But the possibility certainly is good for some other tables i have in mind.