# How can I create a form with multiple radiobuttons/checkboxes and redirect to another page on submit?

Tags: javascript

I want to create a form with multiple radiobuttons/checkboxes and direct the user to a certain page according to the selection when the user has clicked on submit.

[Example of what i'm trying to achieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MfADm.png)

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please read this article on [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). This would include a proper description of what you are trying to achieve, your code (or the relevant snippets) as well as your efforts showing what you have tried so far. It's also helpful to supply more info on your framework/general setup. Just javascript is too general in order to tell you how to do a routing or redirect..

Answer (score 1):

You do not select a button, you tick a checkbox. If that checkbox happens to look like a button, that is already `css` business, not `js`.

You can take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7642277/css-styled-a-checkbox-to-look-like-a-button-is-there-a-hover) at how this could be done.