# checkbox styled as button input:checked background color does not occupy button space

Tags: html, css

I have been looking for ways to turn checkboxes to look like button, I stumbled upon this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7642277/css-styled-a-checkbox-to-look-like-a-button-is-there-a-hover) and I did but I added a padding on mine,

```
.ck-button {
  padding: 5px 5px 0px 5px;
}
```

here is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eaqzruj0/)

As you can see, when clicked, it will just change the color of the span and not the whole button. I tried to add the padding here

```
.ck-button input:checked + span {
  background-color:#0077CC;
  color:#fff;
}
```

or remove the `span` but neither of them is working. Please help me and thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this. You have to give padding to the `ck-button label span` not in `ck-button` class.

```css
div label input {
   margin-right:100px;
}
body {
    font-family:sans-serif;
}

.ck-button {
    margin:4px;
    background-color:#EFEFEF;
    border-radius:4px;
    border:1px solid #D0D0D0;
    overflow:auto;
    float:left;
    /*padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;*/
}

.ck-button label {
    display:block;
    width:5.0em;
}

.ck-button label span {
    text-align:center;
    padding:5px 5px;
    display:block;
}

.ck-button label input {
    position:absolute;
    opacity:0;
    /*top:-20px;  don't use this thing use opacity:0 */
}

.ck-button input:checked + span {
    background-color:#911;
    color:#fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="ck-button">
   <label>
      <input type="checkbox" value="1"><span>red</span>
   </label>
</div>
<div class="ck-button">
   <label>
      <input type="checkbox" value="2"><span>red</span>
   </label>
</div>
```