# checkbox customized to look like a button

Tags: css, reactjs, checkbox

I am trying to create 'checkbox' which look like a button to be able to do this:

[image]

I am trying to customized a checkbox input type to do it, but I am not able to.

```
const CheckBox = 
      <div className="checkbox-style">
        <input className="checkbox-style" onChange={this.toggleCheck} id={this.id} type="checkbox" checked={this.state.isChecked} />
        <label htmlFor={this.id}>test</label>
      </div>
```

Which look like this:

[image]

even when I am applying the css below

```
.checkbox-style {
  border-width: 2px;
  border-color: #ff7255;
}
```

I can't fnd any suitable information on Internet to build this

Answer (score 1):

You can use the code from this S.O. question here: [CSS: styled a checkbox to look like a button, is there a hover?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7642277/css-styled-a-checkbox-to-look-like-a-button-is-there-a-hover)

In case the link stops working, here's the code.

```html
<div id="ck-button">
   <label>
      <input type="checkbox" value="1"><span>red</span>
   </label>
</div>
```

```css
#ck-button {
    margin:4px;
    background-color:#EFEFEF;
    border-radius:4px;
    border:1px solid #D0D0D0;
    overflow:auto;
    float:left;
}

#ck-button label {
    float:left;
    width:4.0em;
}

#ck-button label span {
    text-align:center;
    padding:3px 0px;
    display:block;
}

#ck-button label input {
    position:absolute;
    top:-20px;
}

#ck-button input:checked + span {
    background-color:#911;
    color:#fff;
}
#ck-button:hover {
    background:red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## Declaration

I'm using the code from this link : [CSS: styled a checkbox to look like a button, is there a hover?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7642277/css-styled-a-checkbox-to-look-like-a-button-is-there-a-hover)

but I am also going to explain it step by step.

## Code and Explanation

I will add comments to the code to help you understand better.

1. What you want to do is use `input` instead of `button`.

```
<input type="checkbox" value="1"><span>click me</span>
```

2. and change the type of input to a checkbox.
3. Then change the checkbox's css to look like a button.

```css
div label input {
  margin-right: 100px;
}

body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

/*the input button itself*/
#ck-button {
  margin: 4px; /*so that the text is nicely formatted into our checkbox like button*/ 
  background-color: #555555; /* color of the inital button ( I changed to be greyish to make it look its disabled/inactive*/
  border-radius: 4px; /* to make the button rounded */
  border: 1px solid #D0D0D0; /* give it a bborder of 1px(thin) solid type ( solid | dotted | etc ) and lastly the color #D0D0D0 ( hex code fo the border ). */
  
  color: #aaaaaa; /* color of the text inside I changed it to white*/
  
  float: left; /* just shifts content to the left. */
}

/* on hover what will happen */
#ck-button:hover {
  background: red; /* on hovering the backgorund color will change to red */
  color: black;
  /*on hovering the text color will change to black*/
}

#ck-button label {
  float: left;
  width: 4.0em;
}

#ck-button label span {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 3px 0px;
  display: block;
}

#ck-button label input {
  position: absolute;
  top: -20px;
}

/* when the button is clicked */
#ck-button input:checked+span {
  background-color: #911; /* button is clicked it will change the background color to medium dark shade of red or #911 making it look  like its been pressed .*/
  color: #fff; /* color changes to white #fff when it is clicked.*/
}
```

```html
<div id="ck-button">
  <label>
      <input type="checkbox" value="1"><span>click me</span>
   </label>
</div>
```