# Check box change CSS to looks like Button

Tags: javascript, html, css

In my ASP.NET MVC application, in the view, I created a floating button to view in the right bottom corner of the page.

Then I created a panel that fades on the right side from the middle to the page. For that, I have added a check box and when it is checked, the panel shows and the next click panel will hide.

So I want to know can I change this check box to look like a button.?

This is the floatin button CSS I created

```
<style>
.floating-btn {
        width: 80px;
        height: 80px;
        background: #267410;
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
        text-decoration: auto;
        color: aliceblue;
        font-size: 16px;
        font-style: oblique;
        position: fixed;
        box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.25);
        right: 20px;
        bottom: 50px;
        border-radius: 50%
    }
</style>
```

This is the check box style that currently have

```
  [type="checkbox"]:checked ~ .panel-wrap {
        transform: translateX(0%);
    }
    /* demo display */
    *, *:before, *:after {
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }

    [type="checkbox"] {
        font-size: 1em;
    }
```

Check box

```
<input id="clicker" type="checkbox" />
```

Comment: put your code in a snippet and make sure it works properly to show the issue or your goal

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CSS: styled a checkbox to look like a button, is there a hover?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7642277/css-styled-a-checkbox-to-look-like-a-button-is-there-a-hover)

Comment: Where and what is panel-wrap element.

Comment: You cannot restyle a checkbox to look like a button, but input can be linked to labels. and so the labels can themselves be styled . example to try: `<input id=a type=checkbox><label for=a>click me</label>`   & `label{background:tomato;} #a:checked+label{background:green;}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here I styled the label of an input checkbox as a button, it also shows the active/true/checked state in red.

```css
.checkbox-button {
    margin:4px;
    background-color:#333;
    border-radius:4px;
    border:1px solid #000;
    overflow:auto;
    float:left;
    color: #fff;
    
}

.checkbox-button label {
    float:left;
    width:100px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.checkbox-button label span {
    text-align:center;
    padding:5px 10px;
    display:block;
    border-radius:4px;
}

.checkbox-button label input {
    position:absolute;
    top:-20px;
}

.checkbox-button input:hover + span {
    background-color:#efE0E0;
    color: #333;
}

.checkbox-button input:checked + span {
    background-color:#911;
    color:#fff;
}

.checkbox-button input:checked:hover + span {
    background-color:#c11;
    color:#fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="checkbox-button">
   <label>
      <input type="checkbox" value="1"><span>RED</span>
   </label>
</div>
```